# short protection for LED strip

Tags: led, dc, short-circuit

i'm building a white LED strip to mount above my kitchen counter. there is really nothing fancy about it: it's a 1.7m of 5V LED strip that i soldered an USB plug and mounted an on-wire switch to turn it on/off.it will be powered by an old iphone power adapter (hence the USB plug) and it draws a total of 130mA. my only worry is that being mounted in the kitchen opens up the possibility for water to get accidently spilled on it. is there a way i can build a short protection for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phone chargers are short-circuit protected - they are typically limited to 1A, and will shut off entirely when shorted - so that may be enough protection for you. You could add a lower-current fuse as additional protection. Or just waterproof the connections.